# Passing the variable in the url in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the HTML and Javascript for an application which I built. I am using onlclick function,when I click the button it should take me to the new page.

```js
function editStudent(studentId) {
  console.log(studentId);
  document.location.href = '/student/edit/{{studentId}}' {
    {
      studentId
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Student ID</th>
      <th>Student role</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for each_student in result %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ each_student.student_id }}</td>
      <td>{{ each_student.studnet_role }}</td>
      <td><input class="btn btn-info" type="button" onclick="editStudent('{{each_student.student_id}}')" id="edit" value="Edit"></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

When I click the edit button it goes to the new page with this url http://localhost:6464/student/edit/,
What my expected output is 
/student/edit/studentid(studentid value has to be printed for example if it's 1,it should be student/edit/1)

Comment: You are passing the id, so you need to concatenate that ID and not the template variable. So use `+studentId` or javascript template literal: `location = \`/student/edit/${studentId}\``;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you do concatenation it may work.

```
document.location.href = '/student/edit/'+ studentId
```

Answer (score 0):

Refere this answer,

Some of code removed because `{% for each_student in result %}` will not work here.

You are passing `studentId` to javascript, so just use that variable in javascript function.

```js
function editStudent(studentId) {
  console.log(studentId);
  location = '/student/edit/' + studentId;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Student ID</th>
      <th>Student role</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>student_id</td>
      <td>studnet_role</td>
      <td><input class="btn btn-info" type="button" onclick="editStudent(1)" id="edit" value="Edit"></td>

    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `studentId` is being passed to the function as a Javascript variable, but you're treating like if it was still inside the loop, using `{{studentId}}`. Just use Javascript concatenation:

```
document.location.href = '/student/edit/' + studentId;
```